# Django: How to request data and simultaneously have it editable

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a simple app that gets user input and when a button is clicked, the input is saved as an entry on the database. I'm thinking of creating another app that not only displays the same information (think of view profile) but also simultaneously lets the user edit the text that is displayed in the text field.

I'm guessing the solution is to have the text-fields be auto-filled by pulling the data from the database, and allow overwriting the data once the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically read and edit views are separated for good reasons like avoiding accidental edits, allowing different levels of access, things like that. But this capability does exist in Django via [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/). If you already have a Form built for submitting the data, you can provide a page with existing data pre-filled by initializing the Form instance with the data - in the docs they call this a bound form. [See this example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view) to get an idea of the mechanics.